# How does this word sound to English-speakers?

Tags: pronunciation, international, transliteration

I want to name my project with a word from Ukrainian language. Transliterating it would be spelled as **Ostriv**.

And I'd like to be sure that it doesn't sound bad for English-speakers or isn't hard to pronounce.

Comment: That's not all that different from ***ostrich,*** which is arguably harder to pronounce (as *-ch* is more complicated than the fricative *-v*).

Comment: Spelling is only loosely connected to pronunciation in English; as such, there is no way to spell a word so that it unambiguously represents a single pronunciation. Different people in different parts of the world will pronounce *Ostriv* differently.

Comment: The natural phonetic pronunciation would be similar to *ostrich*, as Andrew suggests (and not unlike *Austria*).  Not very difficult/awkward for most native English speakers.  (Press the loudspeaker icon on the dictionary page for [ostrich](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ostrich) to see how it might sound.  (Note that you need to imagine the "ch" sound replaced with a "v" sound at the end.))

Comment: How is this about English "Language & Usage"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "I'd like to be sure that it doesn't sound bad for english-speakers or isn't hard to pronounce."

Comment: @FumbleFingers Retagged. Pronunication is specifically on-topic.

Comment: @Andrew Leach: I don't expect to win an argument with a mod, but just because the pronunciation of *English* words is On Topic, I don't see how that makes the *potential* pronunciation of a foreign word that has no meaning (or currency) in English On Topic.

Comment: Is it correctly pronounced "AUS-treev," "OH-streev," or "AUS-triv," with a short "i" as in "trivial" and "trip"? Is the emphasis on the first or second syllable? Is it a proper name (e. g., Mr. Ostriv) or does it have a generic, ordinary meaning in Ukrainian?

Comment: @F If the question garners five votes, or a different mod's vote, then that's fine. You've put it in the queue. I think an answer akin to my comment would be reasonable. YMMV.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: I can think of no unfortunate associations with such a term. It is reasonable and wise to ask. I would have warned Toyota about *Cressida,* for instance.

Comment: Define "*sound bad*".

Comment: Well, actually @BrianDonovan got my point. There's a lot of examples of such unfortunate coincidents. And I see from comments that there's no potential problems with my word, wich by the way means "an island". It even has the same emphasis. Thanks to all for their comments!